# How to fetch JSON argument in Tornado's POST handler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

From client I generate post request and in body I have simlpe JSON like

```
{
    "action": "copy_all",
    "id": "aabbababab",
    "factory_id": 12297829382473034000
}
```

How to fetch this argument this in handler (post function) ?
I know how to parse when I send like key/value pair and get argument by key, but here JSON is one argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use:

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```